# Eclipse LESS compiler shows me 3 errors

Tags: node.js, eclipse, npm

I've been trying to compile LESS files to CSS using [Vincent Simonet's "Eclipse plugin for LESS"](https://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.html).

I tried installing these addons using CMD in the folder where my less is installed but it's not working.

This is the error:

> Unable to interpret argument yui-compress - if it is a plugin (less-plugin-yui-compress), make sure that it is installed under or at the same level as less
>
> Unable to interpret argument O0 - if it is a plugin (less-plugin-O0), make sure that it is installed under or at the same level as less
>   The compress option has been deprecated. We recommend you use a dedicated css minifier, for instance see less-plugin-clean-css.
>
> A failure occurred when running the LESS compiler, see above error message.

Comment: The page you linked to has detailed installation instructions: did you follow those? Because from your description, it sounds like you didn't.

Comment: I did. I opened npm folder and in %AppData% and installed these addons using cmd. It's not working.

Comment: that's... not what the installation instructions tell you to do at all? Go read them again, and install the plugin properly.

Comment: not sure what you hoped that comment would achieve, but: if you haven't installed the things you say you rely on properly, then I don't know what you expect from people other than "please first install things properly" because otherwise there is literally no way for us to tell whether the errors you're showing are due to you not following the instructions, or because there's _actually_ something wrong. Right now, the error **strongly suggests** you haven't installed things correctly. "make sure that it is installed under or at the same level as less" does not mean "your .less files directory".